# uncaught exception after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I''ve got this jQuery code code:

```
//some button
var moreButton = $('<a href="#" class="buttonClass">Szczegóły</a>'); 

//load button to the first element with given class
$('.someDiv').first().append(moreButton); 

//after button click we show/hide another div

$(moreButton).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hiddenDiv').slideToggle();    
});
```

So everything is working just fine, BUT the console shows this error:

```
uncaught exception: Invalid arguments
```

after the click event.

I've tried to remove everything from the click function, leaving only some console.log, but the problem still appears.

Comment: On what line is the exception being raised? It could also be an issue with the unicode character in the anchor

Comment: Can not reproduce -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1yf5katu/**, jQuery doesn't throw errors like that !

Comment: There is something else in play. Either another library or other code. You need to prune your page to the bare minimum and see what is causing the issue.

Comment: I thought that the problem might come form '.hiddenDiv' to be loaded via Ajax, but the button is appended after that Ajax call is finished. The whole sliding functionality is working properly.

Comment: The console is giving no hints about the place, where thr problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.. should be like this:

```
//some button
var moreButton = '<a style="cursor: pointer" class="buttonClass">Szczegóły</a>';
```

This supposed to be a string and not a Jquery call

also:

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hiddenDiv').slideToggle();    
});
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, other than it being wrapped more than once

Comment: Even if you do `$($( ... ))` it will still [work](http://jsfiddle.net/enmk3vys/).

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/#example-1)

or

```
var $$ = $.noConflict(true);
//some button
var moreButton = $$("<a>",{
    'href': "#",
    'class':"buttonClass",
    'text':"Szczegóły"
});

//load button to the first element with given class
$$('.someDiv').first().append(moreButton);

//after button click we show/hide another div

$$(moreButton).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $$('.hiddenDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok. It was collision with other code.

What's interesting Safari Developement Tools were more helpful than Firebug.